# displaying values from arrays

Tags: java, android

I have been working this quiz for a little while, however i am struggling to match the the question with the answer.

The following line and the others  which are supposed to be display the answer actually display "[[ljava.lang.string;@40585b18" and slight variations.

```
quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[3]) ;
```

i have tried changing the line now above to:

```
quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[0][3]);
```

Obviously i want the answers to match the questions and the method above only displays 8 from array

```
 {"3","5","8","9"}
```

So basically yeah for each change of question i want them to match. If the questions is "In seconds, how long does it take for a F1 car to stop when travelling at 300km/h?" the answers possible to be displayed should be 4,6,8,10 etc.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated thanks.

Full code below!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MathsMultiplicationActivity extends Activity {


TextView quesnum;
TextView ques;
TextView anst;
TextView ans1;
TextView ans2;
TextView ans3;
TextView ans4;
ImageView cross;
ImageView tick;
Button nxt;

    int qno = 1;
    int right_answers = 0;
    int wrong_answers = 0;
    int rnd1;
    int rnd2;

    String [] questions = {"How much mph does the F-Duct add to the car?",
              "What car part is considered the biggest performance variable?",
              "What car part is designed to speed up air flow at the car rear?",
              "In seconds, how long does it take for a F1 car to stop when travelling at 300km/h?",
              "How many litres of air does an F1 car consume per second?",
              "What car part can heavily influence oversteer and understeer?",
              "A third of the cars downforce can come from what?",
              "Around how much race fuel would be consumed per 100km?","The first high nose cone was introduced when?",
              "An increase in what, has led to the length of exhaust pipes being shortened drastically?"};

    String [] [] answers = {{"3","5","8","9"},
    {"Tyres","Front Wing","F-Duct","Engine"},
    {"Diffuser","Suspension","Tyres","Exhaust"},
    {"4","6","8","10"},
    {"650","10","75","450"},
    {"Suspension","Tyres","Cockpit","Chassis"},
    {"Rear Wing","Nose Cone","Chassis","Engine"},
    {"75 Litres","100 Litres","50 Litres","25 Litres"},
    {"1990","1989","1993","1992"},
    {"Engine RPM","Nose Cone Lengths","Tyre Size","Number of Races"}};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.multiplechoice);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
   quesnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNum);
   ques = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
   anst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answertit);
   ans1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
   ans2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
   ans3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
   ans4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
   nxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
   cross = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cross);
   tick = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tick);

   cross.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
   tick.setVisibility(View.GONE); 


    quesnum.setText("Question: " + qno + "/10");


    final Button buttonAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    buttonAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         next();
        }

        private void next() {
            qno++;
            change_question();
        }

        private void change_question() {
            if(tick.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                right_answers++;
            }

            if(cross.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                wrong_answers++;
            }
            if(qno==questions.length){

            }else{
                cross.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                tick.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                rnd1 = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
                rnd2 = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
                ques.setText(questions[rnd2]);
                if(questions[rnd2]=="x")
                {
                    change_question();
                }
            }
            questions[rnd2]="x";




            if(rnd1==1){
                TextView quesAns1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1); 
                quesAns1.setText("1) " + answers[0]) ;            

                TextView quesAns2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2); 
                quesAns2.setText("2) " + answers[1]) ;   

                TextView quesAns3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3); 
                quesAns3.setText("3) " + answers[2]) ;   

                TextView quesAns4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4); 
                quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[3]) ;   
            }

            if(rnd1==2){
                TextView quesAns1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1); 
                quesAns1.setText("1) " + answers[2]) ;            

                TextView quesAns2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2); 
                quesAns2.setText("2) " + answers[0]) ;   

                TextView quesAns3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3); 
                quesAns3.setText("3) " + answers[1]) ;   

                TextView quesAns4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4); 
                quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[3]) ;  
            }
            if(rnd1==3){
                TextView quesAns1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1); 
                quesAns1.setText("1) " + answers[1]) ;            

                TextView quesAns2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2); 
                quesAns2.setText("2) " + answers[2]) ;   

                TextView quesAns3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3); 
                quesAns3.setText("3) " + answers[0]) ;   

                TextView quesAns4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4); 
                quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[3]) ;  
            }

        }


    });


    //Answer 1 click functions
    ans1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ans1Action();
        }

        private void ans1Action() {
            //enable_disable(0);
            if(rnd1==1){
                tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }else{
                cross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }

        }

    });


    //Answer 2 click functions
    ans2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ans2Action();
        }

        private void ans2Action() {
            //enable_disable(0);
            if(rnd1==2){
                tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }else{
                cross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }

        }

    });


    //Answer 3 click functions
    ans3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ans3Action();
        }

        private void ans3Action() {
            //enable_disable(0);
            if(rnd1==3){
                tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }else{
                cross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }

        }

    });

    //Answer 4 click functions
    ans4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ans4Action();
        }

        private void ans4Action() {
            //enable_disable(0);
            if(rnd1==4){
                tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }else{
                cross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }

        }

    });
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This :

```
quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[0][3]);
```

Works if this is the 1st question.

What you should do is to have in the `change_question` function the number of the question in parameter `change_question(int questionNumber)`

Then, when you set the texts, you use :

```
quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[questionNumber][3]);
```

If your questions start at 0.
Else, you use :

```
quesAns4.setText("1) " + answers[questionNumber-1][0]);
quesAns4.setText("2) " + answers[questionNumber-1][1]);
quesAns4.setText("3) " + answers[questionNumber-1][2]);
quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[questionNumber-1][3]);
```

Comment: i solved the problem. i just had to use the rnd2 int---
change_question(rnd2)----

---quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[rnd2][3]);----

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To print arrays in a user-friendly manner, you need to loop over the array items or you can use the [`Arrays.deepToString` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29):

```
String yourPrinterFriendlyArray = Arrays.deepToString(answers[0]);
quesAns4.setText("4) " + yourPrinterFriendlyArray);
```